# Java8 Non-blocking IO against spawned process

Tags: java, multithreading, io, nonblocking

I would like to spawn an external process from Java and read its output without blocking the reader thread ("Non-blocking IO").
I know the (Socket) Java NIO Selector concept and the brilliant [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) library, but I am wondering, isn't there any built-in solution for that in Java8?

If you want non-blocking IO for consuming the output of an external process and you don't want to include a third party dependency, you you still have to write additional threading code and e.g. use `BlockingQueue` to pass around data read -- is that really all we have got?

Comment: If you already have a reader thread why do you care?

Comment: Not only that, if you *don't* read the process's output it could block and stop running, waiting for its output to be read.

Comment: I definitely want to avoid reinventing the wheel: having some custom made solution works, but maybe in the future I could avoid that?